VBA macro to replace text
I am trying to create a macro that will prompt the user to edit certain lines in a word document. The intent of the macro is so that the user only needs to change content to these lines and not mess with any formatting. I am trying to avoid situations where users will add tabs/carriage returns/spaces etc in places that a report does not need them. There is a template that exists and they should only be editing content. I also want to have the user prompted to edit these specific lines because in the past certain lines of a report have not been changed. Below is my existing code. The issue I am encountering is that since I need to delete the current lines and replace them with the rebuiltText string then all of the formatting (font size, color, alignment) is deleted. This then results in the default formatting (a different font size, color, and alignment). I want to maintain this formatting.
Thank you in advance for your help
The resulting output is text aligned to the right defaulted to calibri (body) 11 point font. My desired output is my matching template (Arial, various lines bolded, certain lines have a different font size, certain lines are a different color and all text is right aligned)
Sub EditSpecificLinesOnFirstPage()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim headerText As String
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim lineIndex As Integer
    Dim response As String
    Dim targetLines As Variant
    Dim rebuiltText As String
    Dim editedText As String
    Dim paraIndex As Integer
    Dim originalText As String
   
    ' Define the specific line numbers to edit (1, 2, 5-12, 14, 15, 17, 19)
    targetLines = Array(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19)
   
    ' Step 1: Prompt the user to edit the header
    headerText = InputBox("Please enter the text for the header:", "Edit Header", ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text)
   
    ' If the user clicks Cancel or enters nothing, exit the macro
    If headerText = "" Then
        MsgBox "Header edit cancelled or no text entered.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' Set the header text of the primary header
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = headerText

    ' Step 2: Initialize the rebuiltText variable
    rebuiltText = ""
   
    ' Step 3: Loop through the paragraphs on the first page
    lineIndex = 1 ' Initialize line counter
    originalText = "" ' Store the original content
   
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        ' Stop once we reach the second page
        If para.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) > 1 Then Exit For
       
        ' Store original text of the paragraph
        originalText = originalText & para.Range.Text
       
        ' Check if the current paragraph is one of the target lines for editing
        If IsInArray(lineIndex, targetLines) Then
            ' Prompt the user to edit the text of this specific line
            response = InputBox("Edit line " & lineIndex & " text (or leave blank to skip):" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & para.Range.Text, _
                                "Edit Line " & lineIndex, para.Range.Text)
           
            ' If the user entered text, update the line
            If response <> "" Then
                rebuiltText = rebuiltText & response & vbCrLf
            Else
                rebuiltText = rebuiltText & para.Range.Text
            End If
        Else
            ' If not an editable line, just append the original text (with its paragraph break)
            rebuiltText = rebuiltText & para.Range.Text
        End If
       
        ' Increment the line index counter
        lineIndex = lineIndex + 1
    Next para
   
    ' Step 4: Replace the entire document content with the rebuilt text
    ActiveDocument.Content.Delete ' Clear current content
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter rebuiltText ' Insert updated content
   
    ' Completion message
    MsgBox "Editing of specified lines on the first page is complete.", vbInformation
End Sub

' Helper function to check if an item is in an array
Function IsInArray(val As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim element As Variant
    IsInArray = False
    For Each element In arr
        If element = val Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function


Instead of an InputBox you would need a custom dialog form with a richtextbox. This would preserve the special formatting.

Not sure why the code is being split up into sections by Stack, but the part that displays on its own in that text box is the body. Everything above is the variable declarations and beneath it is not where i am experiencing any issues

@BartMcEndree Im not exactly sure what you are referring to here, could you provide further detail?

Instead of calling InputBox you would open your own custom made dialog form that uses a richtextbox control instead of a simple textbox. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/creating-a-custom-dialog-box

Why delete and then add new content?  Can you not instead set the Text of the range being edited?   Or maybe consider adding bookmarks for the sections to be edited.

A String cannot store formatting so by storing your text in string variables you are destroying the document. I suggest that you rebuild your “template” using Content Controls where the user needs to replace text. You can then write some code that will check the Content Controls to determine if the user has altered them all and display a message to prompt for any incomplete ones.

This is only an idea also I think @TimothyRylatt using Contentcontrol it is better.
A way is to use the clipboard. Put the text to the clipboard and then use PasteSpecial and keep the format. Something like:
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:= _
wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
